# How To Use String Constant When Setting An SQLite Column Default Value

Tags: java, android, sqlite, default

I know this is probably a simple syntax error, but I am new to SQLite and I 
have searched high and low for this simple answer but I can not. I know it is possible to use String Constants when creating a table as I have done it before, but when setting a default text value it is not working for me. Help please!

```
public static final String USER_TABLE = "USER_TABLE";

   //works fine here!
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + USER_TABLE+
            "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + FFDBSchema.Colz.MODE_ID_COL + "TEXT DEFAULT NULL,"
            //doesn't work here!
            + FFDBSchema.Colz.TABLE_ID_COL + "TEXT DEFAULT "  + 
            USER_TABLE+","
            + FFDBSchema.Colz.ANOTHER_TABLE+ "TEXT,"  +
```

String constants work in other situations but is it simply that I can't use a string constant to set a default column value? Must I insert it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to quote strings with single quotes, so you need to do something like this:

```
public static final String USER_TABLE = "USER_TABLE";

db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + USER_TABLE+
        "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + FFDBSchema.Colz.MODE_ID_COL + "TEXT DEFAULT NULL,"
        + FFDBSchema.Colz.TABLE_ID_COL + "TEXT DEFAULT '" +USER_TABLE+"',"
        + FFDBSchema.Colz.ANOTHER_TABLE+ "TEXT,"  +
```